# RSA в Java__________________

Tags: java, криптография, rsa

У меня имеется, например, сгенерированный `publicKey`. Я с помощью метода `.toString()` сделал из него строковую переменную. Как я могу сделать из нее объект типа `publicKey` (обратное действие методу `.toString();`)
Вот так выглядит та самая строковая переменная. Надо сделать из нее `publicKey`

> 13:23:08 Anonymous: Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits   modulus:
>   21130715513758512048246165404386415659202007430838992703046979367788300865624615505151241454591781805095709634110387667439921119163170599591564603118933764428278634841065449757401479154110381843190148499871101056561477043162842821778693073269481956893210083788435539099322016627008495566825523002874479742907473946490045019978924831345338200001087472544662748551944530961613645062472224786849410306015449422181215236159447845987579979152307457088882132555320135705702398306371534089455846118556462526427865150585790610994384071166073124326858588827554373461026425073908703300847805583912152633870729245428137427131981
>   public exponent: 65537

Answer (score 2):

Метод `toString()` не есть метод сериализации сертификата. Тебе необходимо использовать десериализаторы и сериализаторы:

```
//десериализация из массива байт bobEncodedPubKey
X509EncodedKeySpec bobPubKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(bobEncodedPubKey);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey bobPubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(bobPubKeySpec);
//сериализация в массив байт
byte[] result = bobPubKey.getEncoded()
```

[Оригинал ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21606797/5506820)

Answer (score 1):

Публичный ключ RSA состоит из модуля и экспоненты, которые задаются в виде `BigInteger`, соответственно для сериализации вам надо извлечь модуль и экспоненту сохранить их куда-то, а потом для десериализации сгенерировать обратно публичный ключ из модуля и экспоненты, типа:

```
//извлечение значений ключа
RSAPublicKey publicKey;
BigInteger modulus=publicKey.getModulus();
BigInteger exponent=publicKey.getPublicExponent();

//сериализация значений ключа
String modulusString=modulus.toString();
String exponentString=exponent.toString();

//восстановление ключа
RSAPublicKeySpec Spec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(new BigInteger(modulusString), new BigInteger(exponentString));
RSAPublicKey newPublicKey=KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(Spec);
```